# How to deal with c-string pointers

Tags: c++, loops, pointers, c-strings

I'm new to C++ and I have tried all I now and researched but so far no luck, this is what I'm supposed to do:

- In this assignment you will allow the user to type in a number of short, one line sentences.
- Each sentence is added to a buffer of 500 characters.
- Be sure that each sentence in the buffer is null terminated.
- As each sentence is added to this buffer, store a pointer to the sentence in an array of char pointers.
- When the user enters a zero, stop getting input from the user and display the sentences in the buffer in reverse order.
- Note, the sentences are in reverse order, not the words in the sentences. For example, if the user typed.

I am currently stuck with the first part.

```
int main () {
  int const SIZE = 500;
  char sentences[SIZE];
  char* pointers[SIZE];

  do {
   cout<<"Please enter small sentences, hit enter to continue or 0 to stop: "<<endl;
   cin.getline(sentences, 30);
   *pointers = sentences;
   cin.ignore();
 } while (!(cin.getline>>0));

 system ("PAUSE");
 return 0;
```

}

Can someone help?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Did you get any errors?

Comment: What is the first particular detail you don't understand?

Comment: I cant make the do while loop to work to start with, here is my code I tried but no luck, and it is in c++.thanks                                                             int main ()
{
 int const SIZE = 500;

 char sentences[SIZE];
 char* pointers[SIZE];

 do
 {
 cout<<"Please enter small sentences, hit enter to continue or 0 to stop: "<<endl;
 cin.getline(sentences, 30);
 *pointers = sentences;
 cin.ignore();
 }
 while (!(cin.getline>>0));

system ("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

Comment: also, I'm new to here so I'm not familiar with formatting comments, hope the last comment I posted turn out readable.

Comment: @GamalielTellezOrtiz, it is best if you put your source code into your question.  In your case you put a copy of your source into a comment rather than doing an edit of your question to add it to the question.  In the future, edit your question to provide additional information on your question rather than adding a comment.  That way all the relevant information stays together in one place.

Comment: Thanks to Adam Burry for adding the source to the question itself.

Comment: Why are you creating an array of 500 pointers?  The most strings you could ever put into a 500 char buffer is 250.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**SPOILER ALERT**

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  const int SIZE = 500;
  char sentenceBuffer[SIZE] = {0};
  char* sentences[SIZE / 2] = {0}; // shortest string is a char + '\0'
  int sentenceCount = 0;
  char* nextSentence = &sentenceBuffer[0];

  std::cout << "Enter sentences. Enter 0 to stop.\n";

  while (std::cin.getline(nextSentence, SIZE - (nextSentence - &sentenceBuffer[0]))) {
    if (0 == std::strcmp(nextSentence, "0")) {
      break;
    }
    sentences[sentenceCount] = nextSentence;
    ++sentenceCount;
    nextSentence += std::cin.gcount(); // '\n' stands in for '\0'
  }

  for (int i = sentenceCount - 1; i != -1; --i) {
    std::cout << sentences[i] << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks so much, I'll look throughout to better understand

Comment: @GamalielTellezOrtiz, I hope you try to solve it yourself and come back to my solution if you get stuck.

Comment: `const char* const endOfBuffer = (&sentenceBuffer)[1];`, then the number of chars remaining is just `endOfBuffer - nextSentence`

Comment: You could also use `cin.gcount()` instead of `strlen(nextSentence)`

Comment: @AdamBurry, definaltely since I definitely want to become a great programmer. I'm trying to do it on my own and look at yours for guidance. Thanks again

Comment: @BenVoigt, Thanks. I'll rely on the compiler to see that `SIZE - &sentenceBuffer[0]` is a constant. But I'll make the change from `strlen` to `gcount`.

Comment: You know, if you're going to give the guy the answer you should include comments explaining what you're doing.

Comment: @HotLicks, if the poster cannot figure something out after a reasonable effort, there is always stackoverflow.

Comment: All the help is greatly appreciated, and now with a solid base I'm trying to do it all on my own and looking at the help given.

Answer (score 0):

You are not appending characters to the array, nor are you appending pointers to the pointer array.

Here are some steps you will need to perform:
1. Maintain an index or pointer to the next available location in the "sentences" array.
2. After reading the string from the file file, copy its contents to the next available location in the "sentences" array.  See std::string::c_str() or std::string::data() to convert from string to "char *".
3. Maintain a pointer or index to the next available location in the pointers array.
4. Copy the sentences pointer to the next available location in the pointers array.
5. Advance the sentences pointer by the length of the string.
6. Advance the pointers pointer by one.

Code not supplied, as that will defeat the purpose of the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint - declare the basic data, and you need methods to operate on this data:

```
class Buffer       //buffer data combined with methods
{
private:
    char* buffdata;     //buffer to hold raw strings
    int buffsize;       //how big is buffdata
    int bufflast;       //point to null terminator for last saved string
    char** ray;         //declare ray[raysize] to hold saved strings
    int raysize;        //how big is ray[]
    int raycount;       //count how many strings saved
//methods here
public:
    Buffer() //constructor
    { // you figure out what goes here...
    }
    ~Buffer() //destructor
    { // release anything stored in buffers
    }
    add(char *str); //define method to add a string to your data above
    get(unsigned int index); //define method to extract numbered string from stored data
};
```